# Multiple HTML forms with JS actions - how to disable second button (submit) until first (calculate) button clicked?

Tags: javascript, input, forms

I've never done this double input thing and I'm scratching my head trying to disable the submit button on the "main form" until the preliminary form's calculation is done.

This must be done to pass along the values I need for the next page:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcRoute();">
```

And at the bottom of the page I have a submit button that goes to the next page, in a seperate form like this:

```
<form method="post" name="sendvalues" action="confirm_p2p.php" onsubmit="$.post('confirm_p2p.php';">
....
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="setValue();"/>
```

The problem is that the first calculate button is two input fields so the user ALWAYS presses enter after the second field is filled out. I've tried putting a line that says "click this button before submitting" but even in my small user testing thing everyone pressed enter after the calculation form was complete.

Is it possible to disable the enter submission until the first calculate button has been pressed? I've tried other disable things I found on here but it messes with the ability of the calc form to get the number I need to pass.

Comment: Dynamically added event listeners are much more flexible than using event attributes. They'll make the solution simpler.

Comment: Easy mode: Set a `<input type="checkbox" style="display: none;" required />`, which gets _checked_ by `calcRoute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable a form from submitting, you need to call `event.preventDefault` when its `onsubmit` event occurs. You want it initially disabled, then enabled after the first button is clicked.

On the form `sendvalues`, set

```
onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return false;"`
```

to disable it.

On the `Calculate` button, set

```
onclick="calcRoute(); document.getElementsByName('sendvalues')[0].onsubmit='$.post(\'confirm_p2p.php\');';"
```

Which will enable your other form and also do your POST request (make sure it's synchronous, otherwise the browser will have navigated to the `action` page before it completes).

*You should note that the AJAX request will not send the form data. I don't know what you're trying to do, but your current setup won't work as expected.*

Comment: That worked! I'm still wondering exactly HOW it works, but I'll make sure to figure it out for future use. Thanks a million.

Comment: @kingsofcalabria: You can cancel almost any event, so if you cancel `onsubmit` (through that code in the on submit attribute), the form will not be submitted. Until you remove the canceling code and it can behave normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could do as you are requesting by doing the form submit through JavaScript and writing validation code; however, a better solution might be to use your input's `onblur` event to do the calculation without pressing a button.

It is difficult to tell without your full code but if you can show more I can probably explain better.